# Почему BASH не находит команду, даже если $PATH настроен правильно?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Я установил переменную $PATH в файле /etc/profile таким образом:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/app/cpn/bin
```

Моя команда находится в:
`$ which ydisplay     /usr/app/cpn/bin/ydisplay`

Таким образом, когда я выполняю `echo $PATH`, результат выглядит так:

`$ echo $PATH    ...:/usr/app/cpn/bin`

И все работает нормально, но когда я пытаюсь выполнить то же самое по SSH, то получается такая ошибка:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 ydisplay    $ bash: ydisplay: command not found
```

Но при этом, как видно, мой путь на месте:
`$ ssh 127.0.0.1 echo $PATH    ...:/usr/app/cpn/bin`

Пожалуйста, объясните мне почему так происходит и каким образом надо правильно конфигурировать $PATH?

Самое загадочное для меня то, что если специфицировать $PATH таким же образом в файле .bashrc пользователя, то все работает нормально. Однако мне не хочется модифицировать каждый файл .bashrc для каждого пользователя, вместо этого я хочу делать изменения только в /etc/profile.
Я подозреваю, что это какая-то особенность работы non-interactive Shell.

Comment: Вы конечно же добавляли последней строкой в /etc/profile ?> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/app/cpn/bin

Comment: @pyatak, да

Comment: Тебя конечно такой вариант не устроит?!>  ssh  localhost  ". /etc/profile;ydisplay"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*.profile  файлы используются только при запуске login shell.

Можешь перенести изменение PATH в bashrc или:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 "bash -l -c ydisplay"
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда подключаешся по ссх читается файл с настройками ~/.ssh/environment.

Прочтите

> man 1 ssh

и вы всё поймёте.